# query on maximum minimum of multi-variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Q.How do we find out the sum of absolute maximum and absolute minimum values of $f(x,y)=(x+y)^2-(x+y)+1$ on a unit square $\{(x,y):0<x<1,0<y<1\}$? 
Using the method of $rt-s^2$ its value is zero. So now how do I search for the Max and main value?

Answer (score 6):

write your $$f(x,y)$$ in the form $$(x+y)^2-2\cdot \frac{1}{2}(x+y)+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}$$ and this is $$f(x,y)=\left(x+y-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: However, the original question is very poorly posed. The given function on the given domain doesn't have a maximum! It has a supremum, but it doesn't attain its supremum value. It would've been $f(1,1)$, but the boundary of the square is not included in the given domain.

Comment: You solved the problem! that difference does not exist. Anyway, I suggest in order to calculate were the supremum is a variable change $s=x-y\;t=x+y$.

Comment: After this tried but still taking partial derivative w.r.t both x and y gives the same value . can you tell me the way for ward . I am still stuck with the rt- s^2 =0 condition.